# Eclipse perspective switcher as in google chrome or riena

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, perspectives

Does someone know how to implement eclipse perspective switcher so that each perspective shows as a separate tab on top of the window?

Menubar should be inside tab content, below tabs, as seen in google chrome.

I saw

- [Replacing the Perspective-Switcher in RCP apps](http://eclipsesource.com/blogs/2009/03/31/replacing-the-perspective-switcher-in-rcp-apps/) and
- [Creating your own Perspective-Switcher - A first try](http://www.richclient2.eu/2006_08_29/creating-your-own-perspective-switcher-a-first-try/)

but it's not quite there.

I saw [Riena](http://www.eclipse.org/riena/) [screenshots](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Riena_New_And_Noteworthy) and it looks almost what I have on my mind, but I don't know how they did it. Can someone point me in the right direction?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In Riena specifically, the tabs that you see are 'sub-applications' and not perspectives. Riena has a slightly different approach to the UI and the Look and Feel than traditional RCP / Eclipse applications do.

Take a look at the [Look and Feel section](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Riena_Look_and_Feel) on the Eclipse wiki to get an idea. Also, you could download the source-code and [get started with Riena](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Riena_Getting_started) quite quickly and see for yourself how they do it.

Answer (score 1):

Actually the subapplication in Riena that Anirudh mentions are modelled as RCP perspectives in the inside. So using the Presentation API, when you switch to a different subapplication, Riena will trigger inside to switch to a different perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Check for the plugin preference:

> *org.eclipse.ui./DOCK_PERSPECTIVE_BAR=left*

Read the below for exact details:

[How to change perspective bar pos](http://wiki.eclipse.org/RCP_FAQ#How_can_I_change_the_default_UI_settings_for_the_perspective_bar_location.2C_fast_view_bar_location.2C_etc.3F)

I am not sure whether the above link will take you to the exact index. If not Click on the link and check Question 12: *How can I change the default UI settings for the perspective bar location, fast view bar location, etc?*